Navigating to view on deep link tap with Branch.io
According to the Branch documentation, we're supposed to implement this to navigate to another view when a user taps on a deep link:
@main
struct YourAppNameApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                    Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(url)
                })
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { (params, error) in
            print(params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
            
            guard let data = params as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
            
            guard let options = data["nav_to"] as? String else { return }
            switch options {
                case "landing_page": self.window?.rootViewController?.present( SecondViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
                case "tutorial": self.window?.rootViewController?.present( SecondViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
                case "content": self.window?.rootViewController?.present( SecondViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
                default: break
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}

Which is fine, except I'm using SwiftUI, so using the window and rootViewController to present a new view is not possible.
And they have no documentation to support SwiftUI.
So what do I need to do to navigate to a view when a user taps on a deep link?
Thanks!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui

I think the solution is using in-app notifications, like so:

Define the custom notification and a few useful shortcuts since the NotificationCenter calls are ridiculously wordy:

extension Notification {
    static let deepLinkData = Name("deepLinkData")
}


extension Notification.Name {

    func publisher() -> NotificationCenter.Publisher { 
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: self)
    }

    func post<T>(_ object: T) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self, object: object as AnyObject)
    }
}


Then in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

    Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { params, error in
        if let params = params as? [String: AnyObject] {
            Notification.deepLinkData.post(params)
        }
    }


And finally somewhere in your app's main view:

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .onReceive(Notification.deepLinkData.publisher()) { output in
                guard let params = output.object as? [String: Any] else { return }
                // Your method for dismissing all other views currently presented:
                dismissAll()
                // Show some item specific to your app if it was in the deep link data:
                if let itemId = params["itemId"] as? String {
                    showItemViewer = itemId 
                }
            }
    }

